# Chirp resolution as a function of bandwidth

Tags: discrete-signals, bandwidth, linear-chirp, chirp

My question concerns about the Chirp resolution during the crosscorrelation as a function of the sampling rate and available bandwidth. Suppose at a transmitter a chirp signal is transmitted (ranging in bandwidth from f1 to f2) and at the receiver, the cross-correlation is performed to obtain the peak of the chirp from a "sync"-like output function. I except that given a sampling rate at the receiver the minimum error is proportional to the sampling rate as the peak can be founded between two samples. However, in the radar system, the resolution depends also in the bandwidth in order to detect two chirp peaks between them (maybe here resolution has another meaning). Higher the bandwidth shorten the peak width and higher the resolution to distinguish two objects. However, this is not my case as the only chirp is transmitted a given an ideal case at the receiver (with no echos) the peak detection should depend only on the sampling rate(!?).

Is there any other relationship with the available bandwidth which the signal is distorted and any other effects influence the detection and the resolution (at least theoretically)?

For anyone interested I found this tutorial for the radar system http://www.mouser.cn/pdfdocs/FUnofMMWave.pdf

Regards,

Comment: The Doppler resolution is 1/(B*Tchirp). B= f2-f1 (bandwidth) and Tchirp=duration of the chirp. The sampling frequency needs to be sufficient to avoid aliasing.

Comment: Thanks Harris, what do u mean exactly with doppler resolution. suppose an ideal case, no doppler and echos. At receiver side, i perform the cross correlation with the received chirp. At some point, i wil find the peak. What is the minimum error for the peak to be at the "right" position? To me is unclear how the bandwidth plays role, and if I receive the signal in phase higher the sampling rate(reduce phase offsets) more accurate will be the peak detection. I don't know if I am clear enough or not. Maybe is a dummy question :)